# Python: Img2Pdf is ordering images in the final PDF incorrectly despite naming conventions

Tags: python, concatenation, jpeg, file-conversion, img2pdf

EDIT: Thanks to a commenter I see that the root of the problem is that os.scandir is sorting arbitrarily. However I don't have the skills to follow through.

So I have very little experience. I have a few dozen root-folders that are each full of 8-600 sub-folders each full of hundreds of images; that's to say, many thousands of images to process. The sub-folders are named normally ordered numbers (1, 2, 3,...598, 599, 600) and the contained images are named after the sub-folder and then in order ex. for one of the first sub-folders is 001-001, 001-002, 001-003,...001-239. With the final img collection in the example root folder being completed with img 0022-264.

Think of the images like pages and the sub-folders as chapters. The pages inside each chapter are in order but the chapters themselves are out of natural order.

(If you're curious why I'm using lossless conversion with a lossy file format it's because the original images were png but truncated so I had to first get a program built to batch convert them to JPEG with high tolerance)

The below program correctly goes through all the sub-folders in an inputted root-folder, correctly orders the img  files relative to the sub-folder, however it incorrectly orders the batches of images in the final pdf for example one collection will jump from img 001-045  to 0010-001 to 00100-001 instead of the correct 001-045 to 002-001 in normal order. (This is my first question sorry if the pasted program is not exactly "minimal" but it should be "reproducible".)

```
import os
import img2pdf
from typing import List, Tuple

def convert_images_to_pdf(image_paths: List[str], pdf_path: str) -> None:
    """
    This function takes a list of image paths and converts them into a single PDF file.

    Args:
        image_paths: A list of file paths for the images to be converted to PDF.
        pdf_path: A file path for the output PDF.

    Returns:
        None. Generates a message after the PDF is generated or an error is raised.
    """
    try:
        with open(pdf_path, 'wb') as pdf_file:
            pdf_file.write(img2pdf.convert(image_paths))
        print(f"PDF successfully generated at {pdf_path}")
    except (ValueError, FileNotFoundError) as error:
        print(f"Error occurred while generating PDF: {error}")


def create_folder_pdf(folder_path: str) -> None:
    """
    This function takes a folder path and converts all JPEG files inside the folder and subfolders to create a single PDF file.

    Args:
        folder_path: A file path for the folder that contains images.

    Returns:
        None. Prints a warning message if no images are found, or an error message if an exception is raised.
    """
    try:
        with os.scandir(folder_path) as folder_iterator:
            
            for item in folder_iterator:
                
                if item.is_dir():
                    
                    subfolder_name = item.name
                    subfolder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, subfolder_name)
                    image_paths = []
                    
                    for file in os.scandir(subfolder_path):
                        
                        if file.name.lower().endswith(('.jpeg', '.jpg')):
                            image_paths.append(file.path)
                            
                    if image_paths:
                        pdf_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, f'{subfolder_name}.pdf')
                        convert_images_to_pdf(image_paths, pdf_path)
                        
                    else:
                        print(f"No JPEG files found in {subfolder_name}!")
    except OSError as error:
        print(f"Error occurred while opening the folder at {folder_path}: {error}")
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = input("Enter the path of the folder with JPEG images: ")
    
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        print(f"Path {folder_path} does not exist.")
        
    else:
        create_folder_pdf(folder_path)
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `os.scandir()` returns its results in arbitrary order. Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir): `The entries are yielded in arbitrary order,`. If you want a different order, you need to sort it.

Comment: Alright so I looked up how to sort it and I'm seeing that I can use a library called nat_sort? I also found another solution ```sorted(os.scandir("folder_path"), key=lambda e: e.name)``` but that just returns "Error occurred while opening the folder at ...: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'folder_path'

I don't understand.

Comment: That'sss pretty close, I could try renaming the sub-folders with an A in front of them all. But I'm not exactly jumping to manually change hundreds of folder names.